# Whenever I try to install Atom through Ubuntu Software, it fails!

Tags: software-center, snap

I want to install Atom, which I can do by clicking the 'install' button on 'Ubuntu Software' application. However, every time I click it, so as to install Atom, if fails. Below is a screenshoot of the error that I get. But I don't know what this status code means and how I can fix it: 'snapd returned status code 400: Bad Request' ! 
[Error Message Box when I try to install Atom on 18-11-2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vaNU.png)

George Thornton

Comment: Use the command line instead.

Comment: I simply want somebody to point me towards how I can fix this error, so that this pop-up box, with the status code, appears no more.

Comment: Just type into the terminal: `snap install atom --classic`